# C# FFmpeg rtsp byte stream

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

How can I open a constant byte stream that I can read while it's playing? I am able to get a single image with a resolution of 100:75, but when I bump up the resolution the process never finishes.

I need help improving the performance this method, I'm sure it's possible but I know very little about FFmpeg.

I'd like to be able to:

1. List item
2. Get a full res image
3. Read while the process is running
4. Constantly read byte output from a live stream

This is how I get the single image, it's running on a background thread.

```
string stream = "-i " + url + " -vf scale=100:75 -an -vframes 1 -r 1 -f image2pipe pipe:bmp";

var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = ffmpeg.exe;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = stream;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();

Stream outputReader = process.StandardOutput.BaseStream;

byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    int read;
    while ((read = outputReader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }

    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
    bitmapImage.EndInit();

    bitmapImage.Freeze();
    Image = bitmapImage;
}
```